# Change values from one row to column separated values

Tags: excel, powerquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o34uv.png)

I have first column on the left and I want to transform to column on the right using PowerQuery.
I don't want to use VBA. It must be in PowerQuery.
Do You know the way to transform?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet. You need to at least attempt something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

Name of the Source-Table = "tbl_Shop_SKU"

````
    Quelle = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tbl_Shop_SKU"]}[Content],
    Change_Type = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Quelle,{{"ShopNo", Int64.Type}, {"SKU", Int64.Type}}),
    GroupRows = Table.Group(Change_Type, {"SKU"}, {{"TempTable", each _, type table [ShopNo=nullable number, SKU=nullable number]}}),
    Custom_ShopNo = Table.AddColumn(GroupRows, "List_ShopNo", each [TempTable][ShopNo]),
    Extract_Value = Table.TransformColumns(Custom_ShopNo, {"List_ShopNo", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ","), type text}),
    Remove_other_Columns = Table.SelectColumns(Extract_Value,{"SKU", "List_ShopNo"})
in
    Remove_other_Columns```
````

Best regards
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Assuming table is Table1 you could do this, pasting the text from the steps into Home ... Advanced Editor ....

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ShopNo", type text}, {"SKU", Int64.Type}}),
New= Table.Group( #"Changed Type", {"SKU"}, {{"ShopNo2", each Text.Combine([ShopNo], ";"), type text}})
in New
```

or to save a step, this also converts the numbers to text without the second step

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
New= Table.Group( Source, {"SKU"}, {{"ShopNo2", each Text.Combine(List.Transform([ShopNo], each Text.From(_)), ";"), type text}})
in New
```